# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (148,142,3) into shape (100,100,3)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Try to train my data using this load.py script keep getting this error

tried to convert all images to RGB

```py
############Load libraries#####################################################
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.utils import np_utils
###############################################################################
#cross-validation at the patient level
train_data_dir = 'C:/Users/El_Elyon`s/Desktop/chest_xray/normpneos-trainvalid/trainvalidfull4keras/trainvalidfull4keras/train'
valid_data_dir = 'C:/Users/El_Elyon`s/Desktop/chest_xray/normpneos-trainvalid/trainvalidfull4keras/trainvalidfull4keras/valid'
###############################################################################
# declare the number of samples in each category
nb_train_samples = 22045 #  training samples
nb_valid_samples = 5513#  validation samples
num_classes = 2
img_rows_orig = 100
img_cols_orig = 100

def load_training_data():
    # Load training images
    labels = os.listdir(train_data_dir)
    total = len(labels)

    X_train = np.ndarray((nb_train_samples, img_rows_orig, img_cols_orig, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    Y_train = np.zeros((nb_train_samples,), dtype='uint8')


    i = 0
    print('-'*30)
    print('Creating training images...')
    print('-'*30)
    j = 0
    for label in labels:
        image_names_train = os.listdir(os.path.join(train_data_dir, label))
        total = len(image_names_train)
        print(label, total)
        for image_name in image_names_train:
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(train_data_dir, label, image_name), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            img = np.array([img])
            X_train[i] = img
            Y_train[i] = j

            if i % 100 == 0:
                print('Done: {0}/{1} images'.format(i, total))
            i += 1
        j += 1    
    print(i)                
    print('Loading done.')

    print('Transform targets to keras compatible format.')
    Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train[:nb_train_samples], num_classes)

    np.save('imgs_train.npy', X_train, Y_train)
    return X_train, Y_train

def load_validation_data():
    # Load validation images
    labels = os.listdir(valid_data_dir)


    X_valid = np.ndarray((nb_valid_samples, img_rows_orig, img_cols_orig, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    Y_valid = np.zeros((nb_valid_samples,), dtype='uint8')

    i = 0
    print('-'*30)
    print('Creating validation images...')
    print('-'*30)
    j = 0
    for label in labels:
        image_names_valid = os.listdir(os.path.join(valid_data_dir, label))
        total = len(image_names_valid)
        print(label, total)
        for image_name in image_names_valid:
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(valid_data_dir, label, image_name), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

            img = np.array([img])

            X_valid[i] = img
            Y_valid[i] = j

            if i % 100 == 0:
                print('Done: {0}/{1} images'.format(i, total))
            i += 1
        j += 1
    print(i)            
    print('Loading done.')

    print('Transform targets to keras compatible format.');
    Y_valid = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_valid[:nb_valid_samples], num_classes)

    np.save('imgs_valid.npy', X_valid, Y_valid)

    return X_valid, Y_valid

def load_resized_training_data(img_rows, img_cols):

    X_train, Y_train = load_training_data()
    # Resize trainging images
    X_train = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (img_rows,img_cols)) for img in X_train[:nb_train_samples,:,:,:]])

    return X_train, Y_train

def load_resized_validation_data(img_rows, img_cols):

    X_valid, Y_valid = load_validation_data()

    # Resize images
    X_valid = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (img_rows,img_cols)) for img in X_valid[:nb_valid_samples,:,:,:]])

    return X_valid, Y_valid
```

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     68

---

```
 69 #load data for training
```

> ---> 70 X_train, Y_train = load_resized_training_data(img_rows, img_cols)
>        71 X_valid, Y_valid = load_resized_validation_data(img_rows, img_cols)
>        72 #print the shape of the data
>
> ~\Desktop\final\malaria_cell_classification_code\load_data.py in
>   load_resized_training_data(img_rows, img_cols)
>        94 def load_resized_training_data(img_rows, img_cols):
>        95 
>   ---> 96     X_train, Y_train = load_training_data()
>        97     # Resize trainging images
>        98     X_train = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (img_rows,img_cols)) for img in X_train[:nb_train_samples,:,:,:]])
>
> ~\Desktop\final\malaria_cell_classification_code\load_data.py in
>   load_training_data()
>        37             img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(train_data_dir, label, image_name), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
>        38             img = np.array([img])
>   ---> 39             X_train[i] = img
>        40             Y_train[i] = j
>        41
>
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1858,2090,3)
>   into shape (100,100,3)

Comment: You created `x_train` with the shape (n, 100,100,3).  But evidently the current `img` is (1858,2090,3).  You need to use `cv2` image resizing tools to resize each image to fit the target `x_train` array.  You may need to read more about how to create a training dataset from images that may differ in size.

Comment: thanks a lot I appreciate your response.